# How to add both prefix and suffix to a list in makefile?

Tags: makefile

In my makefile I'm trying to add to each item in the list both prefix and suffix.

For example - assuming the list contains:

```
ITEMS =item1 item2 item3
```

I would like to get this string:

```
ITEMS_PADDED =--before item1 --after1 --after2 --before item2 --after1 --after2 --before item3 --after1 --after2
```

I tried with addprefix and addsuffix commands but it treats the added prefix as items so it add a suffix to the prefix as it was an item:

With the following code

```
ITEMS                   =item1 item2 item3
ITEMS_PREFIX            =$(addprefix ' --before ', $(ITEMS))
ITEMS_SUFFIX            =$(addsuffix ' --after ', $(ITEMS_PREFIX))

list_items:
    @echo $(ITEMS)
    @echo $(ITEMS_PREFIX)
    @echo $(ITEMS_SUFFIX)
```

I'm getting this results:

```
item1 item2 item3
--before item1  --before item2  --before item3
--after  --before --after  item1 --after   --after  --before --after  item2 --after   --after  --before --after  item3 --after
```

which is obviously not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `foreach`:

```
ITEMS         := item1 item2 item3
ITEMS_FOREACH := $(foreach item,$(ITEMS),--before $(item) --after1 --after2)

list_items:
    @echo $(ITEMS)
    @echo $(ITEMS_FOREACH)
```

From the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html